# windows phone 7 + IsolatedStorageSettings + Add and Save function

Tags: windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7 -> IsolatedStorageSettings class we have two functions Add() and Save(). According to me both are doing the same thing meanings saving a key value pair in Isolated Storage. My question what is the difference between these two functions.

To test this what is did was in App.xaml.cs in Application_Deactivated event and Application_Closing event I added one key value pair in IsolatedStorageSettings without calling the save function.

On Application_Launched and Application_Activated event I am retrieving same key value pair and I am getting same value for the key which I had added above.

So, without actually calling Save function of IsolatedStorageSettings I am able to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) actually persists the isolated storage settings instance (such as ApplicationSettings) to the media (e.g. phone storage).

This is automatically done when your application is tombestoned (_Deactivated) or closed (_Closed). That is why you get same value without even calling save.

[.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method just adds a new entry to your dictionary of settings. This change may be missed if your settings is not saved (usually when app is exited unexpectedly).

From MSDN:

> "Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the
>   application that uses the class is closed. This can occur when the
>   user closes the Web browser, refreshes a page, or browses away from
>   the page. If you want your application to write to isolated storage
>   immediately, you can call the Save method in application code."

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Where exited unexpectedly == crashed

Comment: I tried to test this with example you have given, on button click event I added value to key and then wrote following code   string j = "abc"; int i = j.IndexOf("a", 10); meaning exception and then again tried to read the value of key on App_Launch and I got the new value that was added in button click event

Comment: the exception has to be unhandled, you need to make sure in App.xaml.cs there is not code to handle exceptions. also to generate exception try: "throw new Exception()"

Comment: still not working, I removed all the code from Application_UnhandledException event and in button click after adding value to key, I wrote  "throw new Exception()"

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I need to test it again when I got home :)

Comment: No problem, please just update regarding your observations when you get time. Thanks

Comment: Well, I can not reproduce it either, maybe they have changed the way they automatically save it (in 7.1). but as a proof of what I said: "Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the application that uses the class is closed. If you want your application to write to isolated storage immediately, you can call the Save method in application code." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @valipour let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1916/discussion-between-pratik-and-valipour)